# conditionalPanel Display but condition is not met - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have just started to do up the UI using Shiny with R, however I am having some problem with the layout of my page.

The problem I am facing is my second conditionalPanel is showing even though it is not selected. I put the selected='Item1' in my radioButtons, however the  checkboxGroupInput of Item2 is showing as well.

What is the problem here and how do I go around fixing it? Is there any error or mistake in my code?

```
library("shiny")

shinyUI(navbarPage("title",
tabPanel("Subtitle1",
 sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("variable1","Items:",
                         c("Item1","Item2"))),
  mainPanel(
   plotOutput("plot")   
   )
  )
 ),

tabPanel("Subtitle2",
         sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
                 radioButtons(
                     inputId="Item",
                     label="Item Selection:",
                     choices=list(
                         "Item1","Item2"),
                     selected='Item1'
                             ),
# Only show this when Item1 is selected. Become invisible when other Items is selected.
                 conditionalPanel(
                     condition="input.Item == 'Item1'",
                     checkboxGroupInput(
                         "variable2",
                         "Countries:",
                         choices=names(QuantityI),
                         selected= "World.")
                                 ),
# Only show this when Item2 is selected. Become invisible when other Items is selected.
                 conditionalPanel(
                     condition="input.Item == 'Item2'",
                     checkboxGroupInput(
                         "variable2",
                         "Countries:",
                         choices=names(QuantityI),
                         selected= "World.")
                                 )
                        ),
            mainPanel(
                     plotOutput("plot") 
                         ) 
                     )
         )))
```

Comment: I changed it, but it still remain the same.
My second conditional panel still appears

Comment: Actually, your code seems to work, but there is no difference between the conditionalPanel for Item1 and Item2, you created them exactly the same. If you change the Countries to Countries 2 in the second conditionalPanel, you see this changing while altering the input of your radioButtons, hence the code is correct.

Comment: @WannesRosiers The code do work, however, the list of choices is visible  for second condition panel(Item2) even though I am choosing Item1.
I would like Condition panel 1 to be visible when I choose Item1, and Condition Panel 2 to be visible when I choose Item2

Comment: I understand, but both your conditionalPanels are exactly the same, hence even though they are changing, you do not see anything happening, since you are just altering between two exactly the same checkboxgroupInputs.

Comment: @WannesRosiers By right I have another variable for the names(QuantityI), but as I cant source more than 2 scripts to get the variable I need, I am using the same name to try out the layout.
My condition is such as
when Item1 is selected, the checkboxGroupInputs of condition 1 appear, and Item2 remains invisible.
When Item2 is selected, the checkboxGroupInputs of condition 1 disappear, and Item2 appear.
However, that is not the case here.

Comment: Right now, your condition is such that when item1 is selected the checkboxGroupInputs appear, but when item2 is selected the same checkboxGroupInputs appear, that's why you do not see anything changing, try condition="input.Item == 'Item2'",
                     checkboxGroupInput(
                         "variable2",
                         "Second sentence:",
                         choices=names(QuantityI),
                         selected= "World.")
                                 )
and you will see the word Countries: change in Second sentence.

Comment: @WannesRosiers, I understand the label can be changed,
I can change all checkboxGroupInput( "variable3", "Second sentence:", choices=names(QuantityII), selected= "World.") ), but this is not the issue here.
The issue I am having is conditional panel 2 is visible forever no matter what. I want conditional panel 2 to be invisible when it is not selected, same for panel 1.
As I do not have enough rep points here, I am unable to post image for you to see what I am implying.

Comment: I am sorry, but then I can not reproduce your problem: when I alter something, your code is working just fine in my case.

Comment: @WannesRosiers you mean that when you use my code, conditional panel 2 is not showing? only when you select Item2, then it appears? and panel 1 will disappear ??

I am not sure why, but both are visible to me, even when item1 or Item2 is not selected. The coding is working fine, variables can be altered as well, just that I want only 1 panel to show at one time.

Comment: Actually yes, I simplified your code, I will post it as an example, but I did not change anything. So let me know when you have tried it, so I can delete it again.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution to this problem. Thank a lot Wannes Rosiers, where I have found and troubleshoot this error.

For both the mainPanel at tabPanel subtitle1 and subtitle2, 
Both of it were having the same plotOutput, which is "plot",

```
mainPanel(
 plotOutput("plot")   
 )
```

Both of them should have different output, though I am not sure the reason behind it.

Comment: Here you can find why this is not allowed: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/743 The code would generate two HTML elements with the same ID.

Comment: @WannesRosiers Thanks alot for finding out the reasons and helping me through this problem!! I guess it is hard to spot when no error is displayed. =D